# Como adicionar um array dentro de um array?

Tags: javascript, react

Estou criando uma aplicação em ReactJS que bate na API do GitHub e traz o `user` e os repositórios.

Mas eu queria trazer também os *commits* de cada repositório e não estou conseguindo.

Meu código é esse:

```
async handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let user = await this.getUser(this.refs.username.value);
    let repo = await this.getUserRepo(this.refs.username.value);


    for(let i = 0; i < repo.length;i++){
       let commitao = []
       var comitasso = []
       commitao = await this.getReposCommit(this.refs.username.value, repo[i].name);
       comitasso.push(commitao)
       console.log(commitao)

    }
    console.log(comitasso)
    this.setState({
      avatar_url: user.avatar_url,
      username: user.login,
      id: user.id,
      url: user.html_url,
      message: user.message,
      reponame: repo,

    });
```

O problema é que quando faço `console.log(comitasso)`, ele me traz apenas o último registro.

Comment: Já tentou fazer `comitasso.push(commitao[0])`? Ou dar console.log(commitao) antes de dar o `push`?

Comment: Geralmente, o `this.getReposCommit()` deveria trazer um objeto ou um array de objeto, por isso perguntei sobre dar o console.

Comment: pode colocar um exemplo dos dados que retornam em "commitao"?

Comment: @Leandro, Não altere a pergunta para agradecer/indicar que o problema foi resolvido, iniciar uma nova pergunta no mesmo post. A melhor maneira de agradecer e [aceitando a resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) que te ajudou. Por esses motivos eu [reverti a edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/397619/revisions). =D -- De uma olhada em nosso [Tour] para entender melhor o funcionamento da comunidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira ainda mais eficiente de fazer esse loop seria enviar a requisição para buscar todos os commits primeiro, e então esperar a resolução deles simultaneamente, ao invés de enviar a requisição para buscar um commit de cada vez, e então esperar a resolução de cada um antes de buscar o próximo.

```
var promiseComitasso = repo.map(r => this.getReposCommit(this.refs.username.value, r.name))
var comitasso = await Promise.all(promiseComitasso)
```

Não há a necessidade de um `for` aqui pois a iteração do array é feita no `map`.

Comment: Também resolveu! ficou até menos verboso. Gostei assim.
O problema é que não entendo muito das promises ainda =(

Vou buscar entender melhor!

Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você esta definindo a variável `comitasso` dentro do `for`, a cada interação ele vai redefinir, apenas a ultima interação não será redefinida e por isso ela você é a unica que aparece no console, para solucionar basta definir a variável fora do `for` como mostrado abaixo:

```
var comitasso = [];      /// ; <- defina aqui por exemplo
for(let i = 0; i < repo.length;i++){
   let commitao = [];
   // var comitasso = [] /// ; <- comentado
   commitao = await this.getReposCommit(this.refs.username.value, repo[i].name);
   comitasso.push(commitao)
   console.log(commitao)

}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! 
Aliás, eu entendi a lógica agora, rs.
Muitíssimo Obrigado.