# Como adicionar a resposta de uma chamada de API no ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, react

estou criando uma dúvida gerada a partir de outra que havia feito anteriormente.
O link da primeira pergunta é: [Como adicionar um array dentro de um array?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/397619/como-adicionar-um-array-dentro-de-um-array/397653?noredirect=1#comment781280_397653)

Criei essa arrow function pra poder colocar o código na variavel table e retornar ela depois.

Eu gostaria de colocar em cada repositório os dados do seus respectivos commits.

Eu tentei fazer conforme abaixo primeiro dando um console.log. Mas ele me retorna a quantidade de repositórios existentes.

Alguém pode me dar um norte de como adiciono a informação nesse caso?

```
    reposTable = () => {

  let table = []


  for (let i = 0; i < this.state.reponame.length; i++) {
    let repo = []
    let repourl = []

    table.push(
      <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">{repo}{repourl}
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-4"><b>Repository Name:</b><p> {this.state.reponame[i].name}</p></div>
            <div className="col-sm-6"><b>Link:</b> <a href={this.state.reponame[i].html_url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{this.state.reponame[i].html_url}
                            </a></div>
            <div className="col-sm"> <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target={`#`+this.state.reponame[i].name} aria-expanded="true" aria-controls={"collapseOne"}>
                Commits 
              </button></div>
          </div>

            <h2 class="mb-0">
            </h2>
          </div>




          <div id={this.state.reponame[i].name} class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
              {}
              Commit: {console.log(this.state.commits)}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        </div>
    )


}
return table
}
```

Comment: Como vem essa resposta?

Comment: Ela vem repetindo a quantidade de repositorios que eu tenho conforme o print: https://imgur.com/NoO4SiM
Dentro deles, tem os commits de cada repositório:
https://imgur.com/nSx8UuD

Comment: Complicado a sua pergunta tem que disponibilizar um exemplo de como vem e como deseja que fique

Comment: Como vem, vc diz a resposta do console.log(this.state.commits) ? se for isso é oq coloquei nos prints. Na realidade, eu queria usar a resposta dentro da <div class="card-body">, como usei para o nome do repositório um pouco acima ( this.state.reponame[i].name). Mas como a resposta vem com um array e dentro deles vários arrays, eu não sei como pegar a informação e adiciona-la ao campo "Commit". 

Muito Obrigado por sua resposta.

Comment: o que você colocou nos prints tem os arrays precisa abrir um daqueles arrays para ver o seu conteudo ...

Comment: todo projeto dessa forma precisa ter um layout e se você não sabe imagine a gente que tenta ajudar !!!

Comment: Estou colocando a resposta: img: https://imgur.com/Nihzkmo

Answer (score 0):

Talvez isso te de uma direção, geralmente a gente guarda os dados no state do `react` e para a busca de dados o pessoal usa duas maneiras, com `fetch` ou `axios` eu recomendo o `fetch` que é navito, talvez isso responda sua pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204735/react-js-fetch-api